Build and Publish Failed. denied: requested access to the resource is denied
I  have built a CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and Docker. The pipeline was working fine till five days ago. But when I tried to build today, it gave me denied: requested access to the resource is denied at the push step and my build failed.
The only significant change I made during this time is that I updated My docker engine around the same time as my last successful build five days ago. I just don't remember if it was before the build or after the build.
This is the console output for my last successful build :
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
Sending build context to Docker daemon  187.7MB

Step 1/4 : FROM openjdk:17
17: Pulling from library/openjdk
Digest: sha256:528707081fdb9562eb819128a9f85ae7fe000e2fbaeaf9f87662e7b3f38cb7d8
Status: Image is up to date for openjdk:17
 ---> 5e28ba2b4cdb
Step 2/4 : EXPOSE 8081
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a27a4f5b7102
Step 3/4 : ADD target/wordsmith-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war wordsmith-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
 ---> 04ec132f968c
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod","-jar","/wordsmith-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" ]
 ---> Running in 39905ffa8a16
Removing intermediate container 39905ffa8a16
 ---> c3c19e91594c
Successfully built c3c19e91594c
Successfully tagged salahuddinshayan/wordsmith:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[wordsmith] $ docker inspect c3c19e91594c
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
[wordsmith] $ docker push salahuddinshayan/wordsmith
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
WARNING: Support for the legacy ~/.dockercfg configuration file and file-format is deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/salahuddinshayan/wordsmith]
5451b19a11cb: Preparing
dc9fa3d8b576: Preparing
27ee19dc88f2: Preparing
c8dd97366670: Preparing
27ee19dc88f2: Layer already exists
c8dd97366670: Layer already exists
dc9fa3d8b576: Layer already exists
5451b19a11cb: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:a1d6c888c1ed2e8a1e6a0d48246b85686e6d1f8549875899ea659b5be5cb95bd size: 1166
Finished: SUCCESS 

This is the console output for the failed build:
[wordsmith] $ docker build -t index.docker.io/salahuddinshayan/wordsmith --pull=true C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\wordsmith
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 232B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17
#2 DONE 0.9s

#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17@sha256:528707081fdb9562eb819128a9f85ae7fe000e2fbaeaf9f87662e7b3f38cb7d8
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 transferring context: 69.81MB 2.4s done
#5 DONE 2.4s

#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17@sha256:528707081fdb9562eb819128a9f85ae7fe000e2fbaeaf9f87662e7b3f38cb7d8
#4 CACHED

#6 [2/2] ADD target/wordsmith-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war wordsmith-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
#6 DONE 0.2s

#7 exporting to image
#7 exporting layers
#7 exporting layers 0.2s done
#7 writing image sha256:208a62165e9bd213c2f4a0078d7ef863fbf72fba184129bd1e0fc5076b49c163 done
#7 naming to docker.io/salahuddinshayan/wordsmith done
#7 DONE 0.2s
[wordsmith] $ docker push index.docker.io/salahuddinshayan/wordsmith
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/salahuddinshayan/wordsmith]
efe61bd7c8af: Preparing
dc9fa3d8b576: Preparing
27ee19dc88f2: Preparing
c8dd97366670: Preparing
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

I have tried upgrading Jenkins and Its plugins and I have also double-checked my Docker hub credentials, but nothing helped.
I have configured my build using the Jenkins interface, not through a JenkinsFile. I have 2 two build steps. First step Invoke top-level Maven targets with the goal: clean install -DskipTests=true and the second step: Docker Build and Publish.
If possible, I would like to resolve this with the interface only, without going the JenkinsFile route.

I would recommend going the Jenkinsfile route. I've gotten funny behavior with the Jenkins interface that cleared up as soon as I switched to a Jenkinsfile.

I think reauthentication should work.
docker logout
docker login

Or another solution can be:
push or pull without specifiying:
index.docker.io or docker.io
Please go with below:
docker push salahuddinshayan/wordsmith:latest` 


Hey Dike, I have not configured my project using JenkinsFile, but directly through Jenkins interface. Nor have I started my build through a command on a terminal. Can you please tell me how to apply these solutions through the interface?
